Proving a bound on $|\nabla w(0)|$ for a solution to $\Delta w = f(w)$
Let $f \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb R)$ with $0 \leq f \leq 1$ on $\mathbb R$. I am trying to prove the following:

Suppose $w \in C^\infty(B_3(0))$, $w \geq 0$, and solves $\Delta w = f(w)$ on $B_3(0)$. If $w(0) \leq 1$, then $|\nabla w(0)| \leq C$, where $C > 0$ is independent of $w$.

By Interior Schauder estimate,
$$|\nabla w(0)| \leq C' (|f(w)|_{0, 1; B_{2}(0)} + \|w\|_{L^{\infty}(B_2(0))})$$
where $|\cdot|_{0,1; B_2(0)}$ is the usual Holder semi-norm.
Using Harnack's inequality and $w(0) \leq 1$, one can easily bound $\|w\|_{L^{\infty}(B_2(0))}$ by a constant independent of $w$.
However, I am not sure how to bound $|f(w)|_{0, 1; B_{2}(0)}$. We have $|f(w)|_{0, 1; B_{2}(0)} \leq |f|_{0, 1; \mathbb R} |w|_{0, 1; B_{2}(0)}$, but it is not clear how to bound $|w|_{0, 1; B_{2}(0)}$.
I think I am missing some estimate. For example, if Interior Schauder estimate holds for $\alpha = 0$, then proof is complete. But, is this true?
I would appreciate any hint or reference.

Hint: Use the following Schauder estimate:
Let $u\in C^2(B_1)$ satisfy $\Delta u = f $ in $B_1$ with $f\in L^\infty(B_1)$. Then, for any $\varepsilon\in (0,1)$, there holds $$\| u \|_{C^{1,1-\varepsilon} (B_{1/2})}  \leq C \big ( \|u\|_{L^\infty(B_1)}+\| f\|_{L^\infty(B_1)} \big ).$$ Here $C>0$ depends on $n$ and $\varepsilon$.
For a reference, see Proposition 2.27 in Regularity Theory for Elliptic PDE by Fernández-Real and Ros-Oton (and references therein).

Great answer, exactly what I was looking for :) There's a minor typo. The estimate in your answer is Proposition 2.27 in the reference you linked.

Thanks for that. It seems I linked a different version of the document to the one I was looking at. It’s Prop 2.18 in here:https://www.ub.edu/pde/xros/Llibre-ellipticPDE.pdf#page31
